# how to assign different default images to different roles

Tags: users

I have only two profiles, public and registration but I have different roles and would like to add an appropriate default image for each role.

Must I create a separate profile for each role to implement this?

Comment: What do you mean by two profiles?  In Drupal, all users have a user profile, but this is generally the same for all users, regardless of their roles.

Comment: I mean in structure - profile types I have set up two types. One for public and one for registration.

Comment: @CharlieMeany are you using the Profile2 module, or the Profile module which comes default with Drupal 7 (intended to help keep old D6 profiles alive), or something else?

Comment: profile2 is what I am using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display an image for a particular user role , say "Role1" , then in page.tpl

```
 <?php global $user;
  if($user->roles[2] == 'Role1')
 {
 print $logo;
 }?>
```

Just print the $user to get in what values your role is in the role array.

If you print $user, your role may be in this,

```
 [roles](
 [1] = role1
 [2] = role2
 [3] = role3
       )
```

So choose your role and check the condition and accordingly print the $logo however before that get the image in $logo using the image source tag.